# Kafka Manager UI not loaded properly

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

[Kafka Manager UI Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyEWx.png)

I started the Kafka Manager using the below command

`bin/cmak -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf -Dhttp.port=8080`

Kafka manager get started. But when I open the UI, It seems UI did not load properly.

Java Version 17 I am using

`java version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 17.0.8+9.1 (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-jvmci-23.0-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 17.0.8+9.1 (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-jvmci-23.0-b14, mixed mode, sharing)`

Apache Kafka version - 3.5.1
And I started Kafka with Zookeeper

[Kafka Manager Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCNwN.png)

I am trying to start the CMAK (Kafka Manager)  - Expection is UI should properly Load

Comment: Look at the aerver logs?

Comment: I have found the issue, It seems One Issue is already open https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK/issues/844  and They have suggested to pass the extra arguments  

bin/cmak -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf -Dhttp.port=8080 -J--add-opens=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: Yes, Thank You, after passing extra arguments, Java Script gets properly loaded and UI looks good